# DimensionMismatch: matrix A has dimensions (100,7), matrix B has dimensions (1,10)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, julia

I want to train my neural network to classify 7 segments LED digits.The inputlayer in my neural network is 7 for every row in my inputmatrix and the output lyer is 10 for the outputmatrix dimension. But when i want to train it this error comes up:

```
DimensionMismatch: matrix A has dimensions (100,7), matrix B has dimensions (1,10)

macro expansion@interface2.jl:101[inlined]
_pullback(::Zygote.Context{true}, ::typeof(throw), ::DimensionMismatch)@interface2.jl:101
_pullback@matmul.jl:856[inlined]
_pullback(::Zygote.Context{true}, ::typeof(LinearAlgebra._generic_matmatmul!), ::Matrix{LinearAlgebra.Transpose{Float32, Vector{Float32}}}, ::Char, ::Char, ::Matrix{Float32}, ::Vector{Vector{Int64}}, ::LinearAlgebra.MulAddMul{true, true, Bool, Bool})@interface2.jl:0
_pullback@matmul.jl:847[inlined]
_pullback@matmul.jl:407[inlined]
_pullback@matmul.jl:276[inlined]
_pullback(::Zygote.Context{true}, ::typeof(LinearAlgebra.mul!), ::Matrix{LinearAlgebra.Transpose{Float32, Vector{Float32}}}, ::Matrix{Float32}, ::LinearAlgebra.Transpose{LinearAlgebra.Transpose{Int64, Vector{Int64}}, Vector{Vector{Int64}}})@interface2.jl:0
_pullback@matmul.jl:141[inlined]
_pullback(::Zygote.Context{true}, ::typeof(*), ::Matrix{Float32}, ::LinearAlgebra.Transpose{LinearAlgebra.Transpose{Int64, Vector{Int64}}, Vector{Vector{Int64}}})@interface2.jl:0
_pullback@Other: 10[inlined]
_pullback(::Zygote.Context{true}, ::Main.var"workspace#4".Layer, ::LinearAlgebra.Transpose{LinearAlgebra.Transpose{Int64, Vector{Int64}}, Vector{Vector{Int64}}})@interface2.jl:0
_apply(::Function, ::Vararg{Any})@boot.jl:838
adjoint@lib.jl:203[inlined]
_pullback@adjoint.jl:66[inlined]
_pullback@operators.jl:1035[inlined]
_pullback@operators.jl:1034[inlined]
_pullback@operators.jl:1031[inlined]
_pullback(::Zygote.Context{true}, ::Base.var"##_#97", ::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}}, ::ComposedFunction{Main.var"workspace#4".Layer, Main.var"workspace#4".Layer}, ::LinearAlgebra.Transpose{LinearAlgebra.Transpose{Int64, Vector{Int64}}, Vector{Vector{Int64}}})@interface2.jl:0
_apply(::Function, ::Vararg{Any})@boot.jl:838
adjoint@lib.jl:203[inlined]
_pullback@adjoint.jl:66[inlined]
_pullback@operators.jl:1031[inlined]
_pullback(::Zygote.Context{true}, ::ComposedFunction{Main.var"workspace#4".Layer, Main.var"workspace#4".Layer}, ::LinearAlgebra.Transpose{LinearAlgebra.Transpose{Int64, Vector{Int64}}, Vector{Vector{Int64}}})@interface2.jl:0
_pullback@Other: 8[inlined]
_pullback(::Zygote.Context{true}, ::Main.var"workspace#124".Network, ::LinearAlgebra.Transpose{LinearAlgebra.Transpose{Int64, Vector{Int64}}, Vector{Vector{Int64}}})@interface2.jl:0
_pullback@Local: 17[inlined]
_pullback(::Zygote.Context{true}, ::Main.var"workspace#300".var"#1#2")@interface2.jl:0
pullback(::Function, ::Zygote.Params{Zygote.Buffer{Any, Vector{Any}}})@interface.jl:414
gradient(::Function, ::Zygote.Params{Zygote.Buffer{Any, Vector{Any}}})@interface.jl:96
top-level scope@Local: 16
```

How to resolve this error?

```
begin
struct Layer
   W::Matrix{Float32}
   gradients
   b::Vector{Float32} 
   activation::Function
   Layer(in::Int64,out::Int64,activation: 
   :Function=identityFunction) =
   new(randn(out,in),randn(out),activation) 
end

struct Network
  layers::Vector{Layer}
  Network(layers::Vararg{Layer}) = new(vcat(layers...))
end

(m::Network)(x) = reduce((left,right)->right∘left, m.layers)(x)

inputs = [
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],  # 0
    [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],  # 1
    [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],  # 2
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],  # 3
    [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],  # 4
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],  # 5
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],  # 6
    [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],  # 7
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],  # 8
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]   # 9
] 
    
    targetOutput =  [
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],  # 0
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],  # 1
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],  # 2
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],  # 3
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],  # 4
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],  # 5
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],  # 6
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],  # 7
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],  # 8
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]   # 9
] 
    
    mse(x,y) = sum((x .- y).^2)/length(x) 
    
    using Random
    Random.seed!(54321) 
    
    twoLayerNeuralNet = Network(Layer(7,100,ReLu), Layer(100,10)) 
    
    Flux.@functor Layer 
    Flux.@functor Network 
    parameters = Flux.params(twoLayerNeuralNet)

    optimizer = ADAM(0.05) 
    netOutput = [] 
    lossCurve = [] 
    for i in 1:1000

    gradients = Zygote.gradient(
    () -> mse(
    twoLayerNeuralNet(transpose(inputs))[:],
    targetOutput),
    parameters)

    Flux.Optimise.update!(optimizer, parameters, gradients)

    actualOutput = twoLayerNeuralNet(transpose(inputs))[:]
    push!(netOutput, actualOutput)
    push!(lossCurve,
    mse(actualOutput,targetOutput))
    
    end
end
```

Comment: Does this error come with more information? It would be helpful if you cut-and-paste the error into the question (especially if there are line-numbers which would help pinpoint the error location)

Comment: @DanGetz Sorry edited it

Comment: Your issue is that you're using vectors of vectors instead of matrices